# Silverlight 5.0 debugging issue on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-5.0, windows-10

I've recently upgraded my OS to `Windows 10`. I have a very basic `Silverlight 5` application which gives me `Unable to start Debugging. The Silverlight Developer Runtime Not Installed. Please Installed a matching version` error in `VS 2010` whenever I am trying to run the project.

I have :

1. Target Silverlight version is set to `Silverlight 5` in web project.
2. I have installed `Silverlight SDK`, `Silverlight5_Tools with SP1 installed` & `Silverlight Runtime` which is `64-bit`.

After doing all these steps and going through many online posts, still I'm unable to resolve this issue.

My Doubts are :

1. Do the `Windows 10` upgrade has anything to do with this situation?
2. `Windows 10` comes with a new browser `Edge`, is this because of this browser? Like `Silverlight` compability.

Again I am not sure but these are my doubt. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you have a 64 bit OS ?
If so - uninstall Silverlight (developer!) and make sure you install the silverlight.exe (developer!) not the 64 bit version.
That worked for me.
HTH

Comment: install : Silverlight_Developer.exe 
not : Silverlight_Developer_x64.exe

Comment: Well I tried that but it didn't worked. What I did was installed `Silverlight_Developer_x64.exe` and then made ie as a default browser and it worked!!.

Comment: I uninstalled Silverlight,  (not the SDK) and reinstalled. Googled "download Silverlight 5 developer runtime for windows 64 bit"  Be sure to use IE as your default browser as Edge and Chrome won't run SL any more and neither will IE after version 11.  Onwards to typescript and javascript :(

Comment: Contrary to this answer, uninstalling Silverlight and installing the 64 bit version solved the problem for me.

Comment: Hi Craig, maybe your case was like that , and it is 100% ok. Probably there are many other solutions ... once I had RTL problems and MS responded "install Office 97 and the problem will go away...

Comment: One more for whom uninstalling and installing the 64 bit version over did the job.

Comment: Well, I uninstalled the Silverlight, not Silverlight SDK and installed 'Silverlight_Developer_x64'. That worked!

Comment: I am happy for you - @SuyashGupta

Comment: @GuyCohen Hahaha... Me too ;)

Answer (score 7):

Go to the properties of the Web folder start project.  Click Web on the left tab.  Unclick Silverlight in the debuggers.

Not a total solution but at least it allows you to debug other portions.

Comment: This helped me with a standard web application project with the Silverlight option ticked, which on my new development computer didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue and Uninstalling and Reinstalling didn't work.

Error in debug mode (F5 Debug solution configuration) was "Unable to start debugging. The Silverlight Developer Runtime is not installed"

In Debug configuration I would get the above error but finally I put the solution into release mode and it worked - then back to debug mode and everything worked without error.

Seems like a really odd fix but sure enough closing and re-opening the solution everything works now - Same install procedure as OP.

Another thing that's interesting is, the Debug only works in Chrome. If I target IE or edge I still get "Unable to start debugging. The Silverlight Developer Runtime is not installed"

Comment: Thank you very mucg, you're a life saver! :)

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled Silverlight and then installed Silverlight_Developer.exe. I also switched default browser in Visual Studio to Internet Explorer (I have Edge otherwise which won't work...).

Nice to see some more people also using Silverlight these days, hehehe.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old thread, but I just ran into this issue with a project.  I was getting the message that the Developer runtime was not installed, but in fact it was, and another similar project ran just fine on the same machine with the same version of VS 2015.

The fix was to ensure that the startup project is the WEB project, not the Silverlight project.  Somehow, the default startup project got switched to the SL project. After I switched back, then it worked just fine.